# Finding pairs of intersecting sets in a list of arbitrary sets

Tags: python, python-2.7

You have an arbitrary number of sets, for example:

```
sets = [{1,2,3}, {3,4,5}, {5,6,7}]
```

You want to see if any value in one set is also in any other set. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Currently I have the following:

```
index = 0
for set in sets:
    for i in range(index + 1, len(sets)):
        print set, sets[i], set & sets[i]
    index += 1
```

Which results in:

```
set([1, 2, 3]) set([3, 4, 5]) set([3])
set([1, 2, 3]) set([5, 6, 7]) set([])
set([3, 4, 5]) set([5, 6, 7]) set([5])
```

Comment: If this code is working, you should probably be going to http://www.codereview.stackexchange.com.  We are here for helping you solve *bad* code.

Comment: What do you expect your output to look like for your example? I mean, the data structure you continue working with. Right now you are just printing.

Comment: @timgeb I'm actually doing this in a unittest. Instead of printing, I would `assertFalse(set & sets[i])` to prove that there are no intersecting values in any set. I'm using `print` to provide more clarity in the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: If you're going to post this on CR, please include the whole context code - i.e. the actual unit test method.

Comment: @A.J. Your preference to see a question appear elsewhere is [not a bona fide reason to close a question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313266/1157100) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a minor tweak but you can let `itertools.combinations` generate the set pairs for you. This example is python 3 so the representations look a little different, but should work fine in 2.x

```
>>> import itertools
>>> sets = [{1,2,3}, {3,4,5}, {5,6,7}]
>>> for s1,s2 in itertools.combinations(sets,2):
...     print(s1, s2, s1 & s2)
... 
{1, 2, 3} {3, 4, 5} {3}
{1, 2, 3} {5, 6, 7} set()
{3, 4, 5} {5, 6, 7} {5}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 set.intersection(*list_of_sets)
```

will unpack your list of sets and find intersection.